# How to make datepicker-bootstrap input range inline?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to show both calendar next to each other inline and not popping up on click on the input. [Using bootstrap slider](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html#date-range)

```js
$('.input-daterange input').each(function() {
  $(this).datepicker({
    format: "yyyy",
    viewMode: "years", 
    minViewMode: "years",
    updateViewDate: false
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

 <div class="input-group input-daterange">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2012-04-05">
   <div class="input-group-addon">to</div>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2012-04-19">
</div>
```

This is how I use the inline with a single calendar but I can't manage to make it for date range and two calendars:

```
<div id="sandbox-container"><div></div></div>

$('#sandbox-container div').datepicker({
  format: "yyyy",
  viewMode: "years", 
  minViewMode: "years",
  updateViewDate: false
});
```

I tried the following but it place three calendars, the first div with 2 one next to each other and the second div with only one calendar

```js
$('.input-daterange div').each(function() {
  $(this).datepicker({
    format: "yyyy",
    viewMode: "years", 
    minViewMode: "years",
    updateViewDate: false
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

  <div class="input-group input-daterange">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="2012-04-05">
    <div class="input-group-addon">to</div>
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="2012-04-19">
  </div>
```

Comment: where is your script???

Comment: so your date picker is working, but you want place it on right side. Am I correct?

Comment: @Rumesh updated the question with my try out

Comment: On code snippet, your date picker is working, so what is your requirement?

Comment: @Rumesh check the question now, see the second snipped, can you see we have three calendars? Why? We only should see two, one next to the other

Comment: You are adding a datepicker to each `div` via jQuery. As you have 3 divs you get 3 pickers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolevd it eventually:

```js
$('#sandbox-container').datepicker({ 
  format: "yyyy", 
  startView: 1, 
  viewMode: "years", 
  minViewMode: "years", 
  minViewMode: "years", 
  multidate: true, 
  multidateSeparator: ", ", 
  autoClose: true, 
}).on("changeDate",function(event){ 
  var dates = event.dates, elem = $('#sandbox-container'); 
  if(elem.data("selecteddates") == dates.join(",")) return; //To prevernt recursive call, that lead to lead the maximum stack in the browser. 
  if(dates.length>2) dates=dates.splice(dates.length-1); 
  dates.sort(function(a,b){return new Date(a).getTime() - new Date(b).getTime()}); 
  elem.data("selecteddates",dates.join(",")).datepicker('setDates', dates); 
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>


    <div id="sandbox-container">
      <input name="usp-custom-14" id="usp-custom-14" type="text">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps. Some CSS file is missing.

Note : If it helps, [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51046926/pick-a-date-range-in-single-bootstrap-datepicker/51065273#51065273) to select a range in a single datepicker.

```js
$('.input-daterange input').each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
        format: "yyyy",
        viewMode: "years", 
        minViewMode: "years",
        updateViewDate: false
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group input-daterange">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2012-04-05">
    <div class="input-group-addon">to</div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2012-04-19">
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, you have to set `multidate:true` in options while initializing the picker. After selecting a date if you get the value it returns an array of selected dates. But you can select unlimited number of dates. I limited to 2 dates(that means the array has the date-range) in the `onChange` event. So the array contains atmost 2 elements. If it has 1, then only 1 date is selected. Hence it will not be a range.

Comment: How can we only get years in the input in your other answer?

Comment: To show the date in the input, use the options. To get the date in a specified format, Give the format in the getFormattedDate method as I mentioned below.

Comment: this is how I have fortmatted it but it still shows the whole dates and not the year https://pastebin.com/T1n5tFw3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173981/discussion-between-vignesh-raja-and-rob-m).

Comment: What happened to the answer?

Comment: it's back, had thought it wasn't working but actually it does answer, yet the final solution is my own answer as you can see below, what you gave on the chat wasn't working