# bootstrap-datepicker date range with single calendar

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, date-range

I want to make a range date picker with bootstrap with single calendar. Now I have it but with two calendars

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="start" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" />
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

How can I make it with only one calendar? I didn't find answer anywhere

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer for everybody who need it

```js
 $('#date').datepicker({
    startView: 0,
    minViewMode: 0,
    maxViewMode: 2,
    multidate: true,
    multidateSeparator: "-",
    autoClose: true,
    beforeShowDay: highlightRange,
  }).on("changeDate", function(event) {
    var dates = event.dates,
        elem = $('#date');
    if (elem.data("selecteddates") == dates.join(",")) return;
    if (dates.length > 2) dates = dates.splice(dates.length - 1);
    dates.sort(function(a, b) { return new Date(a).getTime() - new Date(b).getTime() });
    elem.data("selecteddates", dates.join(",")).datepicker('setDates', dates);
  });

  function highlightRange(date) {
    var selectedDates = $('#date').datepicker('getDates');
    if (selectedDates.length === 2 && date >= selectedDates[0] && date <= selectedDates[1]) {
      return 'highlighted';
    }
    return '';
  }
```

```css
  .highlighted {
    background-color: #99ccff;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="text" id="date">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Can be achieved usingBootstrap and Datepicker libraries

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Date Range Picker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Date Range Picker</h1>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date-range" placeholder="Select Date Range">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <span class="input-group-text">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#date-range').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'left',
    drops: 'down',
    autoApply: true,
    locale: {
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
      separator: ' - ',
      applyLabel: 'Apply',
      cancelLabel: 'Cancel',
      fromLabel: 'From',
      toLabel: 'To',
      customRangeLabel: 'Custom',
      daysOfWeek: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
      monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
      firstDay: 0
    }
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi. It has to be only one calendar. Also I want it to open month menu when I click on `May 2023` as in my example. I found a possible solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51046926/pick-a-date-range-in-single-bootstrap-datepicker. But It's calendar for month and it doesn't hightlight dates between two chosen dates